# WP_Query Group by Author and Order each group DESC

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to do a query where I get all the posts from a specific category, order/group them by author and in each group order the posts DESC. In the end the author with the newest post will be a the top of the output list.

This is what I use now, but the posts are not ordered as I need them to be.

```
$args = array ( 
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'orderby' => 'author',
 'category_name' => 'cat', 
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$old_author = 0;
if ($query -> have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

 if($post->post_author != $old_author): //check if author changed
  the_author();
  the_title();
 else:
  the_title();
 endif;

$old_author = $post->post_author; 
endwhile; 
endif;
```

I did try to sort the query by date before the query, but the then the author groups doesn't work anymore.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','sort_query');
function sort_query( $query ) {
 if( !$query->is_main_query() ) {
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT 2

My idea in edit one did not work, so I scrapped it. This edit I have sorted the returned array using a foreach loop to sort the posts according to date under the specific author, and the author on top has the newest posts.

The code below is tested and working, so you can try the following

```
$args = array ( 
 'category_name' => 'cat', 
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    foreach ( $query->posts as $post_object ) {
        $new_array[$post_object->post_author][] = $post_object;
    }

    foreach ( $new_array as $k=>$v ) {
        echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $k ) . '</br>';

        foreach ( $v as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            the_title();
            echo '</br'>;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

### EDIT 1

From your comments, neither the method described in my original answer or

```
'orderby'   => 'date author';
```

---**SCRAPPING NOTICE**---

THIS EDIT HAS BEED SCRAPPED

### ORIGINAL POST

I had a lapse in brain power in my comment, I have removed that. Your best possible way would be to try the new [`orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) parameter syntax (*this new syntax came with Wordpress 4.0*).

You can try something like this (*Untested*)

```
'orderby'   => 'author date',
```

Remember to adjust your loop accordingly to remove your ordering inside the loop

Just a note, you need to be very careful with your use of `pre_get_posts`. As you have used it, it will alter **all** custom queries on all pages, front end **and** back end

Comment: It does have some effect. The posts get sorted for each author group, but the author output remains the same.
If i reverse the order then the posts are no longer grouped by author correctly.

    `'orderby'   => 'date author',`


Thank you for the heads up, I removed the pre_get_posts.

Comment: Ok, then we will need to scrap this idea. Then my brain lapse is the best option, set `orderby` to `date`, and then inside the loop sort with `usort` according to author. I will try to work something out here. It might take time as I'm still at work, and I don't really have time tonight to code due to other responsibilities. :-)

Comment: Something like this? Doesn't actually do as expected, but maybe I'm missing something. 

`function order_author($a, $b){  //The function to order our authors
  if ($a->post_author == $b->post_author) { 
    return 0;  
  }  
  return ($b->post_author < $a->post_author ) ? -1 : 1; 
}  
usort($query->posts, "order_author");`

Comment: Please see my edit 2. My first edit did not work on testing. Edit 2 works, I have tested it. Hope it works for you

Comment: Thank you a lot for the solution. It does work. Unfortunately in my particular case, because I use the Co-author Plus Plugin I can't get it to work properly in terms of showing both authors if the post has 2 authors. Also the pagination doesn't work properly anymore. Still, thank you for taking your time and coming up with a solution. I will try and see if there's a way I can make it work with co-authors. Thank you again. :)

Comment: My pleasure. I don't think pagination should be a problem. `$query->max_num_pages` still hold the correct info for pagination. Just remember to add the `paged` parameter in your custom query arguments. I hope you get the other problem solved. I have never worked with co authors, so I cannot advice you on that issue unfortunately. Good luck :-)